# onsubmit return false does not work, form still submits?

Tags: javascript, html

This is the code

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script>
        function test() {
            return false;
        }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form method="post" action="../test.php">
            <input type="submit" onsubmit="return test()">
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

how is the form still submitting, it makes no sense to me??

Comment: the form has onsubmit not the button

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to stop form submission, when user submits it by **click**ing the `submit` button in the form.

Change `onsubmit` of the `submit` button to `onclick`

```
<input type = "submit" onsubmit= "return test()">
```

Should be

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return test()">
<!--                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -->
```

If you want to use `onsubmit`, you can use it on `form` element.

```
<form method="post" action="../test.php" onsubmit="return test()">
<!--                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -->
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Tushar is asking you to change `onmousenter` by `onclick`. Did you tried that?

Comment: @LostProgrammer The answer still remains the same, I've also add `onsubmit`, check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>

<head>
    <script>
    function test(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post" action="../test.php" onsubmit="return test(event);">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
```