# Message prompted up onsubmit return validate but form still submits

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation

I am having some issues which is quite similar referring to this [onsubmit return false does not work, form still submits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32220441/onsubmit-return-false-does-not-work-form-still-submits)
I've followed the solution but if I changed it to onclick, it won't work, not even a message prompts out.

Script that I am using.

```
<script>
function validate()
{
  var validate = false;
  if(document.getElementById("nameId").value == "")
  {  
    alert("NAME IS REQUIRED");
    validate   = false
  }

return true ;
}

</script>
```

My codes are attached in below.

```
<table class="<?php echo $table_style_3;?>" style='width: auto;'>
<form action="fhd_add_type.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal"   onsubmit="return validate()"> //This is the part where i've changed to onclick
<input type='hidden' name='nacl' value='<?php echo $nacl;?>'>
<input type='hidden' name='type' value='<?php echo $type;?>'>
<?php
if ($type <> 0) { ?>
    <tr><td>Name: </td><td><input type='text' name='type_name' id = "nameId"></td></tr> //This is the field where need to be validate
    <tr><td colspan='2'><input type='submit' value='add' class='btn btn-primary'></td></tr>
    </table>
<?php  }
if ($type == 0) { ?>
    <tr><td>Name</td><td><input type='text' name='type_name' id = "nameId"></td></tr> //This is the field where need to be validate
    <tr><td>Email</td><td><input type='text' name='type_email'></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Location</td><td><input type='text' name='type_location'></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Phone</td><td><input type='text' name='type_phone'></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan='2'><input type='submit' value='add' class='btn btn-primary'></td></tr>
    </table>
<?php }?>
</form>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is because you're always returning `true`. In your JS, try this:

```
<script>
function validate()
{
  var validate = true;
  if(document.getElementById("nameId").value == "") {  
       alert("NAME IS REQUIRED");
       validate = false;
    }

    return validate;
}
</script>
```

Comment: update your script by this it is working great
<script>
function validate()
{
  var validate = false;
  if(document.getElementById("nameId").value == "")
{  
   alert("NAME IS REQUIRED");
   return false;
   //validate   = false
}

return true ;
}

</script>

Comment: hi @Clonkex i've up voted your post too, don't worry. haha, it works too

Answer (score 2):

Well you always return true from `Validate()`. It should be more like the following:

```
<script>
function validate()
{
  var valid = true;
  if(document.getElementById("nameId").value == "")
  {  
    alert("NAME IS REQUIRED");
    valid = false;
  }

  return valid;
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**solved your issue**

```
<script>
function validate()
{
  var validate = false;
  if(document.getElementById("nameId").value == "")
{  
   alert("NAME IS REQUIRED");
   return false;
   //validate   = false
}

return true ;
}

</script>
```

**update your script by this script
**

Comment: update your script by this it is working great  <script>
function validate()
{
  var validate = true;
  if(document.getElementById("nameId").value == "") {  
       alert("NAME IS REQUIRED");
       validate = false;
    }

    return validate;
}
</script>