# form onsubmit="return function()" but form still submitting and page reloading

Tags: javascript, forms

I want a form to not submit and reload the page. Instead I want it to run the `runTest()` function.

I've tried the following:

```
<form id="dataForm" onsubmit="return runTest()">
    <input type="text" id="text" placeholder="enter some text" required maxlength="10" pattern="^[a-z,A-Z]{1,10}$"><br />
    <input type="text" id="number" placeholder="enter a number" required maxlength="10" pattern="\d{10}"><br />
    <input type="submit" id="submitTest">
</form>
<script src="../test/test2.js"></script>
```

and in `../test/test2.js:`

```
function runTest() {...}
```

However, the form submits and the page reloads, and `runTest()` does not run.

Help appreciated.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44403445/667903), I've altered my `runTest()` function to be:

```
function runTest() {

    var validate = true;
    describe("Simple assert", function() {
        it("foo != bar", function() {
            assert('foo' != 'bar', 'foo is not bar');
        });
        it('should return true if field is valid', function(){
            var isValidText = isValidField('text');
            var isValidNumber = isValidField('number');
            assert.equal(isValidText, true);
            assert.equal(isValidNumber, true);
        });
        validate = false;
    });
    return validate;
}
```

`runTest()` has been browserfyd into `test2.js`

However, the form still submits, the page reloads, and `runTest()` does not run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle the submit event of the form programmatically with Javascript using the `addEventListener` function as below:

```js
document.getElementById("dataForm").addEventListener("submit", function(e){
  e.preventDefault() //to block page reload
  var validate = true;
  describe("Simple assert", function() {
      it("foo != bar", function() {
          assert('foo' != 'bar', 'foo is not bar');
      });
      it('should return true if field is valid', function(){
          var isValidText = isValidField('text');
          var isValidNumber = isValidField('number');
          assert.equal(isValidText, true);
          assert.equal(isValidNumber, true);
      });
      validate = false;
  });
  return validate;
})
```

```html
<form id="dataForm">
    <input type="text" id="text" placeholder="enter some text" required maxlength="10" pattern="^[a-z,A-Z]{1,10}$"><br />
    <input type="text" id="number" placeholder="enter a number" required maxlength="10" pattern="\d{10}"><br />
    <input type="submit" id="submitTest">
</form>
```

Comment: I can't bring `runTest()` into the `.html` file because it is typescript in an external file that has been browserfy-d into a javascript file.

Comment: i never asked you to put the script in your `.html` ;).... Normally it should work in your browseryfied file

Comment: OK. So does the `document.getElementById("dataForm").addEventListener("submit", function(e)` go inside `runTest` ? Because the rest of the code in your answer is. :)

Comment: No.. Instead on calling `runTest` when the form is submitted, i handle the submit event with javascript; so i replaced the `runTest` declaration by `document.getElementById(...` ... I think it's more professional like that

Comment: Okay. We're getting somewhere. The form does not submit and the page does not reload now. I'll need to work out why the asserts are not running now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can programmatically submit the form later by doing `document.getElementById("dataForm").submit(); `

Comment: I found I needed to move `mocha.run();` from the bottom of the `index.html` file to end of the function you provided. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

pass event in your html.

```
onsubmit="return runTest(event)"
```

and then call preventDefault in your function and return false at the end.

```
function runTest(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   .
   .
   .
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried that and the form still submits / page reloads.

Comment: @Steve also `return false` at the end of function.

Comment: Tried that too, same thing happens. :)

Answer (score 1):

Change the type of that button to `button` instead `submit` then submit your form using JavaScript like this

```
document.getElementById("dataForm").submit();
```

and remove the return part from you onclick attribute.

Comment: I tried that. I end up with [this code](https://pastebin.com/UufLWZXC), but the browser gets trapped in a loop.

Comment: You are directly including this statement document.getElementById("dataForm").submit(); inside script element so when the page load your form automatically get submitted .

Comment: Right question would when to call that method and the simple answer is that when you want to submit the form if you want to submit your form after the runTest function completes then you should call that submit method at the end of runTest function.

Comment: OK. I see [this](https://imgur.com/a/m8SeAFQ) in my code editor when I place it at the end of `runTest`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code,

use `e.preventDefault();`
dont send the response as a veriable
use `return false;` instead of `return validate;`

```
function runTest() {
    e.preventDefault();
        describe("Simple assert", function() {
            it("foo != bar", function() {
                assert('foo' != 'bar', 'foo is not bar');
            });
            it('should return true if field is valid', function(){
                var isValidText = isValidField('text');
                var isValidNumber = isValidField('number');
                assert.equal(isValidText, true);
                assert.equal(isValidNumber, true);
            });
           return false;
        });

    }
```

or

```
 function runTest() {

        var validate = 'true';
        describe("Simple assert", function() {
            it("foo != bar", function() {
                assert('foo' != 'bar', 'foo is not bar');
            });
            it('should return true if field is valid', function(){
                var isValidText = isValidField('text');
                var isValidNumber = isValidField('number');
                assert.equal(isValidText, true);
                assert.equal(isValidNumber, true);
            });
            validate = 'false';
        });
alert(validate)
        if(validate=='false'){
             return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: please try my second ans,  I add a code to alert the value of the variable validate. so you can easy to check

Comment: @Steve : Then there is an error in the above codes. please add an alert() in function top. and also check your script path is correct

Comment: I've added an alert just inside runTest() and it doesn't fire. [I have the path correct I believe](https://imgur.com/a/LPfWlIF).